# Stein and Shakarchi: "positive counterclockwise orientation"

Tags: complex-analysis, orientation

I am having trouble understanding a passage in Stein and Shakarchi's complex analysis textbook. Here is the passage for reference. (It earlier wrote $z = re^{i \theta}$ and then wrote Euler's identity.)

> Since $|e^{i \theta}| = 1$ we observe that $r = |z|$, and $\theta$ is simply the angle (with positive counterclockwise orientation) between the positive real axis and the half-line starting at the origin and passing through $z$.

I think I have a very minimal understanding of what an "orientation" is. I have seen this defined as the order of basis vectors. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, this is the order of the three standard basis vectors, I believe, and it tells me what the "positive" direction for $x$, $y$, and $z$ are. I don't think I know what this means with respect to an angle, even though I'm aware that $\theta$ is measured counterclockwise and, as I move counterclockwise around the complex plane, $\theta$ increases from $0$ to $2\pi$.

So my problem is that my understanding of orientation is extremely superficial at best. Can someone help to grasp this passage?

Comment: First glance in the same book page 20, and the concept itself on a more general level can be started with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability.

Comment: @zkutch I see the definitions on page 20, but I'm not sure how to relate the two, as this seems to be parametrizing a specific curve. Is the analogy with the parametrization for polar coordinates? If so, I'm not sure how the "positive" and "negative" bit comes into play.

Comment: To have one specific curve orientation, the parameter transformations are constrained to strictly increasing mappings. The transition from one orientation to another is obtained by a strictly decreasing mapping. The choice of the names themselves from the outset is, of course, arbitrary.

Comment: Is the idea that, for some fixed $r$ and point $(x,y)$, we define moving around the circle counterclockwise to be an increasing value of $\theta$, so this effectively forms a curve unto itself?

Comment: circle counterclockwise is set of equivalent curves, where one is classical $z(t)=z_0+re^{it}, t\in [0, 2\pi]$ and others are obtained from it by only strictly increasing parameter transformations.

Comment: @zkutch So polar coordinates is just a concatenation of all of these curves for all $r > 0$?

Comment: Polar coordinates are one of representations of circle.